# About the convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences such that $a_n$ is bounded. How do I show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=0$?

It is given that $a_n$ is bounded, and that's it. We do not know if $b_n$ is bounded or monotone, just that $a_n$,$b_n>0$. I think there is missing information, or maybe there is something I might not see.

Any hint for this problem?

Comment: I think, you want to show that if $(a_n)$ is bounded and $b_n \to 0$ then $a_n b_n \to 0$.

Comment: There is definitely missing information, probably about convergence. Take $a_n = 1$, for instance (constant sequences are definitely bounded) and $b_n = n$ (and so $a_n b_n > 0$), but clearly $b_n \to \infty$.